# Dimensional Killer: A bullet from another dimension or parallel universe?

Tags: weapons

Let's assume that parallel universes or dimensions exist. I would like to know what are the hypothetical properties needed to make a sniper rifle (and the bullets) that can snipe a person in dimension or universe A from dimension or universe B.

Comment: This was done, on a rather larger level, in *Children of the Lens* be E.E. Doc Smith, 1951. It required a hyper-spacial tube or vortex to connect the two spaces, and a super-intelligent alien who had studied multi-spaces for eons to compute the vectors (since human-built computers couldn't handle that kind of math).

Comment: It depends on the method of parallel traveling you use, and how you can know what is happening in the other universe. For example if there are no restrictions to where you can make a passage to the next universe you could try and make the portal in your targets head, or just open a portal below them and drop them in a killchamber where you can identify if you got the right victim afterwards. If there are restrictions they will greatly affect what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

**Waste of Energy**

The amount of energy required to connect two places from two separate universes is quite literally astronomical. Possibly the equivalent to the mass of a galaxy converted into energy at 100% efficiency. If you can create and manipulate such energies you are in quite literal terms, a god. When you can unmake galaxies why even bother with a single man, let alone something so underpowered as a gun?

Comment: I'm interested what you base this on? If I had a wild guess and based travel on the energy of the vacuüm quantum field thingies (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_energy) than it would take the amount of energy to nullify your quantum field to vacuüm state and make it appear in the quantum field of the other universe. If we assume energy isnt transferred between universes this would create energy out of the dissapearing matter on the universe that creates the passage and require energy to form at the other end.